# Can I parameterise the build machine?

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to create a branch builder job. Our build servers are usually busy running nightly master builds, so I was thinking I could set people's personal machines up as slaves to Jenkins, and have them run the branch builder locally, kicked off from Jenkins

When I try and put a parameter in the machine restriction list, I get and error:

> (pending—There are no nodes with the label ‘${BuildMachine}’)

Where BuildMachine was a selection of which machine to build on.

Is this possible, or is the list supposed to be restricted to all available machines only?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're talking about "traditional" jobs, like Freestyle, Maven, or Multijob (as opposed to Pipeline or Multibranch Pipeline). Please let me know if that's not the case, as the answer will likely be very different.

The restriction list does **not** allow you to use a parameter/variable (or even a wildcard or regex). Instead, you should take a look at the [Node and Label parameter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodelabelparameter):

> This plugin adds two new parameter types to job configuration - node and label, this allows to dynamically select the node where a job/project should be executed.

Once installed:

1. Go to the job configuration and check **This project is parameterized**.
2. From the **Add Parameter** dropdown, select **Node**.
3. You can set the parameter name, choose a default node, and optionally allow all or a subset of nodes to be selected.
4. When you next run the job, you'll be able to select the node from a dropdown.

**Caveat:** Once a node/label parameter is added, the "Restrict where this project can be run" entry will be ignored; probably best to uncheck the selection to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes, it is "traditional". It was copied from a job from an older version of Jenkins. I shall have a look into that plugin - thanks